# Form displaying an error in frontend TYPO3

Tags: forms, typo3, typo3-extensions

I have followed every tutorial on Form. In every tutorial after I finish their steps the form appears in front-end. My form displays this error:

> Oops, an error occurred! Code: 20220818062042eaedc27c

I have installed a sitepackage in my page and created some custom masked element but nothing I think to interfere with the Form module. What could be causing this?

Answer (score 0):

Since I am new to TYPO3 I have made a noob mistake. Anyway I am leaving the answer here for anyone to see. Also this does not apply only to this case, just be careful to not forget to include this for other extensions as well:

[image]

This should work after that, if not just give a flush cache and you should be good.

Comment: Nice that you could solve it yourself. "Ooops, an error ..." in the frontend gives you a number that you can use to find the actual error message in the log files `[typo3temp]/var/logs/typo3...`.